# Custom border Windows Form and Scrollbar visibility

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to create a custom border window using Windows Form. Currently I am using WM_NCCALSIZE to modify the size of the border, and WM_NCPAINT for custom-drawing.
I realize that when I do not call base WndProc when processing the WM_NCCALSIZE message, the scroll bar will not be painted.
So, can I have a native, normal scroll bar if I handle WM_NCCALSIZE manually? And how can I do it?

Comment: Yes, I could. But I have searched on the internet and nobody call base method. I wonder if it make a overhead or other problem when we do that?

Comment: That really depends what the base implementation does with `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, but I doubt you should see any measurable effect. If it gives you the desired result, go with it :)

Comment: Thank you. Although I really want a solution that do not need to call base method (which only call native DefWndProc procedure), but I think it is a acceptable solution.
Could you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: Posted as an answer. Btw, I'm pretty sure the base implementation does call the native `DefWndProc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is first call `base.WndProc(ref m)` and then process the message to modify the size of the border.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        ...
        case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            //Work your magic...
        }
        default: base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```